# Speeding up comparision of lists in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to compare a list of tags in a cell of a pd.DataFrame (`sports.pubdf`) with the list of another cell and yield the hits and non-hits in a list of another column.
To do so, I am using nested loops like

```
for i in sports.pubdf.index:
hitlist=[]
falselist=[]
print("Control: {0} of {1}".format(sports.pubdf.index.get_loc(i), len(sports.pubdf.index)))
for meshterm in sports.pubdf['Supplemented MeSH-Terms'][i]:
    if meshterm in sports.pubdf['auto-MeSH-Terms'][i]:
        hitlist.append(meshterm)
        sports.pubdf.set_value(i,'Hits',hitlist)
    elif meshterm not in sports.pubdf['auto-MeSH-Terms'][i]:
        falselist.append(meshterm)
        sports.pubdf.set_value(i, 'Non-Hits',falselist)
```

This works, but it is really slow (length of about 3600 rows takes some minutes). I know there should be a possibility with the `np.where` but my version is not working:

```
sports.pubdf['Hits'] = np.where(pubdf['auto-MeSH-Terms'].isin(sports.pubdf['Supplemented MeSH-Terms'])
```

It says "object has no attribute 'isin' "???

Any suggestions?

Comment: isin() is a dataframe method. pubdf['auto-MeSH-Terms'] is a series object. Did you try pubdf['auto-MeSH-Terms'].str.contains() ?

Comment: Never iterate over pandas dataframes unless you absolutely have to. If you absolutely have to use builtin iterators like `iterrows()` and `itertuples()`.

Comment: @Sword: I tried contains() but had troubles with the re-pattern as described in the <a href="http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html">doc</a>. I took pubdf['auto-MeSH-Terms'].str.contains(meshterm) as pattern

Comment: @Khris: if I use 'iter()', how can I write the matchlist row by row?

Comment: Usually when using `iterrows()` e.g. you do it like this `for i,row in df.iterrows()`. But you're better off trying to find a solution with `np.where` since that is lightyears faster. In any case please add examples of your data frames to your question, the data you are using, and the expected output.